# Solid Gauge chart losing series rendering on page/container resize [ng-highcharts + angular]

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, highcharts, gauge

I have customized a solid gauge chart and it works fine when run on a simple html container

**Check this [JS Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/roydondsouza/m4hzg181/)**

But after integrating it with angular and ng-highcharts the series data loses its rendering.

**Check this [JS Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/roydondsouza/6hxaB/139/)**

**Expected look:**

[image]

**After Resize: (Most of the time during rendering):**

[image]

It would be great to have a work around this problem, spent a lot of time trying to fix it. 
Thanks.

```
//See: https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["highcharts-ng"]);

myapp.controller('myctrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.chartConfig = {
        options: {
                chart: {
                        renderTo: 'container',
                        type: 'solidgauge',
                        height:100,
                        width:100,
                        spacingTop: 0,
                        spacingRight: 0,
                        spacingBottom: 0,
                        spacingLeft: 0,
                        plotBorderWidth: 0,
                        marginRight: 0, //-60, //this does move the chart but you'll need to recompute it
                        marginLeft: 0, //-60,  //whenever the page changes width
                        marginTop: 0,
                        marginBottom: 0
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: ''
                    },
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    pane: {
                        size: '99%',
                        startAngle: 0,
                        endAngle: 360,

                        background: {
                            //innerRadius: '50%', #fix for inner border :D
                            outerRadius: '101%',
                            backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
                        }
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        solidgauge: {
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: false,
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        labels: {
                            enabled: false
                        },

                        min: 0,
                        max: 100,
                        gridLineColor: 'transparent',
                        lineColor: 'transparent',
                        minorTickLength: 0,
                        tickInterval: 67, //supply value from API
                        tickPositions: [67], //from api 67%
                        tickColor: '#000000',
                        tickPosition: 'outside',
                        tickLength: 4,
                        tickWidth: 1,

                    },

                },

             series:[{
                    innerRadius: '70%',
                    data: [{y:55,color:'red'}],
                    radius: '55%'
                }, {
                    innerRadius: '85%',
                     data: [{y:55,color:'orange'}],
                    radius: '70%'
                }, {
                    innerRadius: '100%',
                    radius: '85%',
                     data: [{y:25,color:'green'}],
                }, {
                    innerRadius: '101',
                    data: [{y:57,color:'black'}]
                }],

            loading: false
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you found anything on this by chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is evidently a problem with the solid gauge plugin. There is an issue [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3708) and a corresponding patch [in this commit](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/commit/69af87e3f74df98ccbed2743a6e43d3d95e77f60) that can be applied to your solid gauge code file.

Comment: Yes,  the patch you mentioned fixes the issue. Thanks